# "Живой поиск" jquery php

Tags: jquery, php

[image]

Как сделать так же, т.е при вводе в input буквы, внизу появлялась строка с похожими результатами из базы к примеру ники.

[image]

И можно было их выбрать.

Comment: с базами данных можно связать?

Comment: ответ-вопрос?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам [сюда](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/)